# How to protect user's files

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

My application stores use file like the following approach:

```
/app
  |-static
  |   |-img
  |   |-css
  |   |-js
  |-server 
  |    |-models
  |    |-routes
  |-files
     |- 594873
          |- file.txt
              .
              .
     |- 393948
```

Folder 'files' contains private user files. 594873 and 393948 are user ids. So I need to make a secure aproach for writing and reading user's files. On a backend I use NodeJS/express/mongoose.

I need to make something like this:

```
app.get('/getfile/:userid/:filename', function (req, res) {
   // Return file that contains in 'userid' folder and named 'filename'
 });
```

**EDIT:**

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
```

Comment: I'd say: start with a system to authenticate users, like [Passport](http://passportjs.org). After that, create a middleware to check if a user should be able to access the files.

Comment: I have user authentication. Can you provide a code snippet for checking file access?

Answer (score 2):

Say you're using something similar to [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) to authenticate users, and the user object is stored in `req.user`, and that object contains an `id` property, you can create a middleware which checks for the correct access:

```
var checkValidUser = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user && req.user.id && req.user.id === req.params.userid)
  {
    // user has access, calling 'next()' will pass the request to the handler
    next();
  }
  else
  {
    // user doesn't have access, return an HTTP 401 response
    res.send(401, 'Unauthorized');
  }
};

app.get('/getfile/:userid/:filename', checkValidUser, function (req, res) {
  // this will only be called when 'checkValidUser' allowed access to this file
  res.sendfile('./files/' + req.params.userid + '/' + req.params.filename); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I protect file getting against directly access?

Comment: Via what URL can the files be directly accessed? Do you have an `express.static` which might be able to handle those files as well? In that case, just don't use it and let the handler above handle all requests for files in the `files` directory.

Comment: I want to protect files from the following: 'GET http://mysite.com/files:594873/file.txt'

Comment: That looks like you have a static file handler as well. Could you post your application setup? (`app.use()` and such)

Comment: Thanks :) Do you have another route that handles `/files:594873/file.txt`? (I assumed that the : should have been a / and that it would get handled by `express.static`, but that doesn't seem to be the case)

Comment: So your approach is secure for my application?

Comment: Well, unless you have another route for handling those files, the only entry point for them is via `/getfiles/:userid/:filename`, which is secured. Of course, you should test for yourself if everything works as expected :)